# Collect OpenTelemetry traces with DataDog

Tags: .net, datadog, open-telemetry

I have the following OpenTelemetry setup:

```cs
builder.Services
    .AddOpenTelemetry()
    .ConfigureResource(ops =>
    {
        ops.AddService(builder.Environment.ApplicationName).AddTelemetrySdk();
    })
    .WithTracing(ops =>
    {
        ops.AddSource("*");
        ops.AddAspNetCoreInstrumentation();
        ops.AddHttpClientInstrumentation();
        ops.AddConsoleExporter();
    })
    .WithMetrics(ops =>
    {
        ops.AddMeter("*");
        ops.AddConsoleExporter();
    });
```

I can see the traces in the console, so this setup works fine.

However, I would also like to collect these traces in DataDog. After spending a couple of hours, I did not find any way to make it work. This is my DD tracer setup:

```cs
var datadogTracerConfig = TracerSettings.FromDefaultSources();
datadogTracerConfig.Exporter.AgentUri = new UriBuilder(HttpScheme.Http.ToString(), configuration.Host, configuration.TcpPort).Uri;
datadogTracerConfig.Exporter.DogStatsdPort = configuration.UdpPort;
datadogTracerConfig.Environment = environment.EnvironmentName;
datadogTracerConfig.ServiceName = environment.ApplicationName;
datadogTracerConfig.ServiceVersion = version;

Datadog.Trace.Tracer.Configure(datadogTracerConfig);
```

This setup is working as well. I managed to send traces to DD. However, I'm not able to combine the two. I tried the following approach:

```cs
var tracer = OpenTracingTracerFactory.WrapTracer(Datadog.Trace.Tracer.Instance);
GlobalTracer.Register(tracer);
```

But, it is not working. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OpenTelemetry != OpenTracing, so the following will not work.

```
var tracer = OpenTracingTracerFactory.WrapTracer(Datadog.Trace.Tracer.Instance);
GlobalTracer.Register(tracer);
```

I'm not familiar with DataDog's products, but you can configure OpenTelemetry .NET to export its telemetry over OTLP (OpenTelemetry Protocol). [DataDog says they support OTLP](https://www.datadoghq.com/blog/ingest-opentelemetry-traces-metrics-with-datadog-agent/).

Your code should look something like:

```
builder.Services
    .AddOpenTelemetry()
    .ConfigureResource(ops =>
    {
        ops.AddService(builder.Environment.ApplicationName).AddTelemetrySdk();
    })
    .WithTracing(ops =>
    {
        ops.AddSource("*");
        ops.AddAspNetCoreInstrumentation();
        ops.AddHttpClientInstrumentation();
        ops.AddOtlpExporter(options =>
        {
            options.Endpoint = new Uri("https://address-of-ddagent-or-otelcollector");
        });
    })
    .WithMetrics(ops =>
    {
        ops.AddMeter("*");
        ops.AddOtlpExporter(options =>
        {
            options.Endpoint = new Uri("https://address-of-ddagent-or-otelcollector");
        });
    });
```